# How can I truncate string in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf-2, java-ee-5

How can I truncate string in JSF2 ?
Say I have a really long name and I only want to display 5 characters how can I do that? I know I use backing bean what any better options.

Comment: Something like `substring(0,4)`? A Before/After example would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use JSTL `fn:substring()`